# How to stop an SSRS report with optional parameters from rendering

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that has multiple parameters. The user will filter the data by inputting a value in to one of them.

All the parameters are created by the query and have the following design `(fieldname = @param OR @param IS NULL)`

In the parameter properties window, they have been changed to allow NULL values. The issue with this, is that the report renders initially with all data returned, as each parameter has the NULL checkbox ticked as default. From there you can input a value to one parameter and the report will filter as desired.

I would prefer the report not to render until one value has been given to one of the parameters. I am aware I can use a default value for one of the parameters, which would return no data, but this isn't ideal, as you still get the rendering of the report.

Is there a way to run the report but not render until a value is passed to one parameter?

Comment: I believe if you don't default one of the parameters it should not render by default. If I'm not mistaken, that includes the NULL option. Maybe you could include a hidden parameter that isn't used but isn't defaulted? Seems a bit hokey but might work.

Comment: Why not set up your SQL statement so that is `NULL` is passed for every value no data is returned? Although any of the parameter can be `NULL`, at least one appears that it has to be.

Comment: @Larnu can you add a bit more detail to your suggestion please?

Comment: Just put `IF (@Parameter1 IS NOT NULL OR @Parameter2 IS NOT NULL OR ...)` before your statement. As this looks like a catch-all query I'm hazard a guess it's a dynamic statement, so you could put the line before the `sp_executesql` statement.

Comment: @Larnu Currently just a standard query, but will be a Stored Proc when I have finished designing report.

Comment: @Larnu Are you saying I need to add this statement to the start of a SP? So after I have declared the variables, and before the SELECT statement?

Comment: Directly before the statement that returns the data.

Comment: @Larnu Ok, I have setup the SP with the IF statement, however when you run the report, it still renders with no data in the table. I was hoping to avoid that, and get the report to only render when one of the parameters is given a value. Is this not possible?

Comment: You would need to use a solution like what @JacobH suggested for that. I was suggesting an alternative.

Comment: @Larnu Have tried that, but you get an error 'no value passed to hidden parameter', so the report doesn't render, but the error is not good for the user. Your alternative has changed my initial render from all data to no data, which is probably preferred, so thanks for the help.

Comment: That's because when *at least* one of the parameters has a non-`NULL` value you need to give the Hidden parameter a value.

Answer (score 0):

-Write a custom code that checks the parameter value

```
Function GetReportCode(ParamVal AS String) As integer
Return IIf(ParamVal Is Nothing, 1/0, 0)
End Function
```

-If your parameter value is NULL then it will return an arithmetic overflow error

-Create a new variable with help of the following experision.

```
code.GetReportCode(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value)
```

- If the parameters takes `NULL` values it will return an error.

Comment: So you write the code in the 'report properties' pane, but where should the expressions be written? Not sure how this will achieve what I want, basically to behave like a report that requires a parameter value before rendering. Also, no error messages etc

Comment: Let me know, you have a parameters and if this parameter value is null you want to cancel the rendering.